# How to write/insert (Embed) the image object into the excel in Selenium WebDriver (POI Jar ) using Java Programming language?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, excel, embedded

I want to insert (Embed) the image object into the excel file using poi jar. In Excel, we can able to do manually shown in the below screenshot. Similarly, I want to insert an image object through the selenium web driver. So that I can automate the process.
[image: Image inserted as an object]

Comment: Do you want to manipulate Excel files with Selenium?

Comment: https://www.guru99.com/all-about-excel-in-selenium-poi-jxl.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991473/apache-poi-insert-image